# Understanding how Google playstore measures its crashes per 1000 devices

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have been deploying android apps to the google playstore, and I have always wondered how Google calculated its crash per 1000 devices. Because, for an app that crashes once or twice a day on over a 1000 devices, it shows numbers that I can't really grasp, with huge percentages as you can see in the image below.

[image]

I have read what they mean by crash per 1000 devices. But can someone please tell me how it is calculated ?
And also, could anyone please share what are their crash per 1000 devices ratio ? I'm willing to know what is the acceptable range for this stat for a good app ?